# Using testing.T in TestMain

Tags: go, grpc, gomock

There are a few test cases I want to run for which there is a need to start a GRPC mock server. I am using `gomock` library for this. To start the server, I have to pass a variable of type `testing.T` to this function - [`gomock.NewController()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/mock/gomock). Since this is a kind of initialization for all the test cases, I want to do this in `TestMain`. But `TestMain` has access to only `testing.M` So how do I handle this case? Create a new `testing.T` structure in `TestMain`? Will it work?

Comment: As TestReporter is only an interface, you may try to create yours: https://github.com/golang/mock/issues/122#issuecomment-338743825

Comment: You can't create a testing.T instance because all fields are not exported. Forget about TestMain and start the server in each test individually. That's best practice in general.

Comment: please provide some code example of your main function. I am sure you have too much things inside. With a little refactoring of your main function the testing will be then much easier.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you are looking for a `BeforeEach` pattern. You don't have access to a `testing.T` object in `TestMain` because this is something more of a place to do initialization before and after the test suite runs.

There are a few frameworks out there that can give you a `BeforeEach` cheap:

- [Ginkgo](https://github.com/onsi/ginkgo)
- [Onpar](https://github.com/poy/onpar)

to name a few.

You could also hand roll your own:

```
type test struct{
  ctrl *gomock.Controller
  mockFoo *MockFoo
  // ...
}

func beforeEach(t *testing.T) test {
  ctrl := gomock.NewController(t)
  return test {
    ctrl:ctrl,
    mockFoo: NewMockFoo(ctrl),
  }
}

func TestBar(t *testing.T) {
  test := beforeEach(t)
  // ...
}

func TestBaz(t *testing.T) {
  test := beforeEach(t)
  // ...
}
```